# How to create a react native polyfill?

Tags: ios, sockets, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react native

Are there any tutorials that I can reference to create a react native polyfill?

I am now planning to contribute a tcp/udp socket polyfill for react native

thanks for your answer!

Comment: if you create TCP and UDP polyfills, please make their API nodejs compliant, see https://nodejs.org/api/net.html and  https://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html

please DM me and I will beta test them for you!

Comment: there's a udp pollyfill here that gives you node dgram's api: https://github.com/tradle/react-native-udp

Comment: here's a tcp pollyfill for node's net api: https://github.com/PeelTechnologies/react-native-tcp

Answer (score 1):

There's no specific tutorial, however the [Native Modules](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/nativemodulesios.html#content) section of the documentation is really all you need. It explains how to expose Obj-C methods, properties and events to JavaScript - which is pretty much all you'll need to do to in order to create a polyfill.

Also take a look at some of the polyfills that have already been written, such as [the XHR polyfill](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Libraries/Network), as that should give a better idea of how to approach this from a practical point of view.